# Error al copiar imágenes de una carpeta a otra de forma recursiva

Tags: java, netbeans

Estoy usando Netbeans y quiero copiar imágenes de una carpeta a otra. Todo funciona bien cuando no hay subcarpetas. El problema es que si tengo una subcarpeta, no copia las imágenes que contiene ésta. Necesito copiar todas las imágenes, incluidas las que están dentro de las subcarpetas de manera recursiva. El código contempla si encuentro un directorio, de nuevo llama al método recursivo, pero no encuentro el error. ¿Alguna sugerencia?

```
   public static void recursivo(File ruta) {

String user = System.getProperty("user.name");

File[] listarFichero = ruta.listFiles();
if (listarFichero != null) {

    for (int i = 0; i < listarFichero.length; i++) {

        if (listarFichero[i].isDirectory()) {
            try {
               
                recursivo(listarFichero[i]);
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }

        } else {

            if (listarFichero[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Thumbs.db") || listarFichero[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase("Desktop.ini")) {
                listarFichero[i].isHidden();
            }

            try {
         
                CopiarDeUnaCarpetaAotra.copia("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos\\" + listarFichero[i].getName(), "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos\\pipi\\" + listarFichero[i].getName());

            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}}
```

Este método copia las imágenes de una carpeta a otra:

```
   public static void copia(String ficheroOriginal, String ficheroCopia) {
try {
    
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ficheroOriginal);
    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);

    
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(ficheroCopia);
    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);

   
    byte[] array = new byte[2048];
    int leidos = bis.read(array);

    while (leidos > 0)
    {
        bos.write(array, 0, leidos);
        leidos = bis.read(array);
    }

   
    bis.close();
    bos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 
}catch(Exception e){
       e.printStackTrace();
}}
```

Comment: No dejes los bloques catch vacíos, eso te va a dar un indicio de por donde pueda estar el error.

Comment: Primero, como se dijo en el comentario anterior, debe tener al menos un e.printStacktrace() en todas sus try..catch, de lo contrario no hay forma de saber qué error está sucediendo. En segundo lugar, no necesita todo el método que utilizó para copiar archivos, solo puede importar java.nio.file.Files y usar el método Files.copy (origen, destino, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución para copiar de una carpeta a otra. En lugar de estar leyendo y escribiendo arrays de bytes como hacía en el método 'copia' de la pregunta, con la clase FileOutputStream.... he usado la librería java.nio.file.Files, Path y Paths.

Con siguiente método copiaría el contenido de una carpeta a otra, incluyendo todos sus directorios:

```
    public static void recursivo() throws IOException {

    String user = System.getProperty("user.name");

    Path from = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos");
    Path dest = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\pipi");

    try (Stream<Path> stream = Files.walk(from)) {
        stream.forEachOrdered(source -> {
            try {
                Files.copy(source, dest.resolve(from.relativize(source)), StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Gracias a ambos.

Comment: ¿Podrías [edit] tu respuesta y explicar brevemente qué hace el código? Otros usuarios llegarían a ella y podrían no comprender su funcionamiento.

Answer (score 2):

El problema lo tienes en la siguiente línea

```
CopiarDeUnaCarpetaAotra.copia("C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos\\" + listarFichero[i].getName(), "C:\\Users\\" + user + "\\OneDrive\\Fotos\\pipi\\" + listarFichero[i].getName());
```

por varias razones

1.- Independientemente de la ruta que ingreses, buscas copiar los archivos desde la ruta "fija" C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Fotos\ + listarFichero[i].getName().

2.- Al entrar a una subcarpeta, ya no vas a encontrar los archivos en el mismo path.

3.- El código que tienes solo funcionara para la carpeta base, por los dos 2 puntos anteriores y después de la siguiente ejecución te va a marcar error por que el archivo ya existe en la ruta destino.

Comment: En primer lugar, gracias Israel por tu comentario y por la respuesta que aportas. Se hace notar, que has realizado un análisis de mi código, y eso siempre es de agradecer. En segundo lugar, como dice el usuario res, la optimización utilizando la librería java.nio.file... optimiza muy mucho el código. De manera que, una solución para el caso que expongo sería utilizar dicha librería. A continuación el código.